# In org-mode, how to cancel task scheduling?

Tags: org-mode

This seems trivial, but if you attempt to schedule a task and change your mind, how do you just cancel without actually setting a task.

`C-j` exits, but sets the date (like return)

`C-k` kills the active buffer, but doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the org mode info pages, section `8.3.1 Inserting deadlines or schedules`:

> ```
> `C-c C-s     (`org-schedule')'
>      Insert `SCHEDULED' keyword along with a stamp.  Any CLOSED
>      timestamp will be removed.  When called with a prefix argument,
>      remove the scheduling date from the entry.
> ```

So you can abort the input `C-g` and call the scheduling with a prefix argument `C-u C-c C-s` to remove the date/time.